# How can I extract and use a column for ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to extract a column from a dataframe and use the same for a histogram

```r
ggplot(data=data1$X_5_5)+hist()
```

Here, X_5_5 is the name of the column. However, I'm getting the following error message:

```r
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an integer vector
```

I don't understand how a column extracted from a dataframe is not a dataframe.

Comment: It's not, it's a vector. Pass the dataframe and use aes to determine the column used for the histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a column extracted from a `dataframe` is a vector, and you don't have to extract it to use it in ggplot, just do this to works:

```r
ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = X_5_5)) +
    geom_histogram()
```